# Let (X, d) be a metric space and let A be a subset of X. Prove that A is closed if and only if Fr(A) $\subseteq$ A.

Tags: real-analysis

The direction from closedness to Fr(A) being contained in A is quite easy.
But I don't see how I can do the if direction.

Comment: Can you please define  $Fr(A)$?

Comment: Sorry. It's the frontier of A, namely its the compliment of the union of the exterior and interior.

Comment: @davidh a more common term for this notion is the *boundary* of a subset. Are you possibly translating from another language? or what reference is using this term?

Comment: I'm using the text by Copson called Metric Space, this is the term used in that book. Thanks for pointing out other notions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $Fr(A)\subset A.$ Let $x \in X-A$.

If $x\in cl(A)$. So $x\in cl(A)-A\subset Fr(A)$. It's a contradiction.

So $x\notin cl(A).$ Then, $x \in cl(A) \Rightarrow x\in A$. Hence $A$ is closed.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $Fr(A) \subseteq A$ and let $(a_n)$ be a convergent sequence in $A$ with limit $a$. We have to show that $a \in A$.

Case 1: $a \in A$. Then we are done.

Case 2: $a \notin A$. Then $a \in Fr(A)$. Hence $a \in A$.